# Forcing external script to fire onLoad

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I have a page (page1), which loads a different page (page2) into a modal popup. This new page (page2) has two external scripts, which should be fired on page load. This works fine, if I load the AJAX page by itself, but when I attempt to call them from the other page (page1), they don't fire at all.

Now, the tricky part is, that the script is inserted by a user into a CMS, script tags included — and the scripts are actually just links to external scripts on a different server (LinkedIn). Fun fun fun!

Is there anyway at all I can force these scripts to fire on load anyway?

Comment: wild-guessing-mode: Those scripts "activate" themselves via `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: No, the scripts are regular <script> tags with a src to the scripts provided by LinkedIn (on their server). I am not dynamically retrieving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you hitting a security issue here. You can not make calls via AJAX to different domains, this is to prevent cross domain scripting vulnerabilities. There is no solution if like in this case you dont have control over the external page (linkedin)

Comment: Damn, I didn't think about that. So even if the page that is called, and which references the scripts are on my domain, the scripts are not fired, because they are pointing to a different domain?

Would the only feasible solution be to download the scripts and place them locally?

Comment: Well that depends on what this scripts do, but that might work